# Intent don't work when I set <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />

Tags: android

I use the following code to open a new UI:

```
String name="com.hellocw.exportmsg.mysettings";
Intent intent1 = new Intent(name);
startActivity(intent1);
```

It works well in Case Two, but failed in Case One. Why? Thanks!

**Case One**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  

    <activity android:name=".MainPreferenceActivity"
              android:label="Settings">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.hellocw.exportmsg.mysettings" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Case Two**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  

    <activity android:name=".MainPreferenceActivity"
              android:label="Settings">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.hellocw.exportmsg.mysettings" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not adding `CATEGORY_PREFERENCE` in your Intent, quote from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

> **The categories**, if supplied, must all be listed by the activity as categories it handles. That is, if you include the categories CATEGORY_LAUNCHER and CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE, then you will only resolve to components with an intent that lists both of those categories. Activities will very often need to support the CATEGORY_DEFAULT so that they can be found by Context.startActivity().

So, in order for your activity to be resolved for `CATEGORY_PREFERENCE` you have to explicitly list it. For example,

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.hellocw.exportmsg.mysettings");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_PREFERENCE);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks!   but why needn't I add intent.addCategory(...) when I set  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

Comment: And more, I get the same error even if I add intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_PREFERENCE);